# How do I limit the Google Drive Picker UI to displaying just Google Documents?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-picker

The [reference guide](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#otherviews) suggests that I can use the `addView()` function to specify which Google Drive items are included. That's great but despite this the recommended view for Google Documents only - `google.picker.​ViewId.DOCUMENTS` seems to also include any files that are uploaded to drive and are a document, e.g. MS Word formats, Open Office Formats, Plain Text and Rich Text Formats.

Is there any way to limit the Picker to just offer the user Google Documents?

Just for clarity here's my code to instantiate the Picker.

```
this.picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
            addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCUMENTS).
            setAppId(this.clientId).
            setOAuthToken(accessToken).
            setCallback(this._pickerCallback.bind(this)).
            build().
            setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it transpires that Google's rebrand that combined Drive with Docs resulted in some inconsistent naming. Google Drive Documents actually refers to any Document stored in Google Drive, including but not limited to those file types listed in the question.

To get around this you can create a View rather than use an existing View and specify the MIME types you're interested in being able to list.

Here's the code incase anyone else find's themselves stuck.

```
var view = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCUMENTS)
    .setMimeTypes("application/vnd.google-apps.document");

this.picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
            addView(view).
            setAppId(this.clientId).
            setOAuthToken(accessToken).
            setCallback(this._pickerCallback.bind(this)).
            build().
            setVisible(true);
```

Thanks for this goes to a user in the Google Drive Developers community on G+

[Original Post in the G+ Community](https://plus.google.com/113843858453459029478/posts/41XZEZ38Xu4)

Comment: Thank you! For other mime types: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types. To show multiple types (e.g. Documents and Presentations), you need to provide a comma-separated list of mime types within the single string argument to setMimeTypes()